# Filing State Tax Returns as an Out-of-state College Student

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, new-york, pennsylvania

I have a permanent residence in Pennsylvania, and I attend college in New York. Currently, I earn no income in PA, but I do have a job on-campus.

My question is this: which state tax return(s) should I file if I choose to do so this year? I'm not required to file a return, but I have been considering it. How would this change if, say, I earned income in both states (e.g., a summer job)?

Comment: Will your parents be claiming you as a dependent?

Comment: Maybe you should ask your student employment office?  They've surely dealt with this question many times.

Comment: @MichaelC. I asked them that earlier today (they just filed them this morning), and they said no.

Comment: @jamesqf I did not consider that. I will talk to them as soon as I can. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You will need to file taxes in both states](https://www.rapidtax.com/blog/state-income-tax-living-in-one-state-working-in-another/#.WIQ9RlMrLRY), first filing in PA because they have the right to all taxes you earned since you are a resident of that state. After that, then you'll file as a non-resident with New York. However, as the article states, you don't need to worry about being double taxed. The [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch01.html#en_US_2016_publink1000170388) also has regulations on if you need to file taxes. As someone who is presumably single (i.e. not married) then you don't have to file taxes if you're gross income was below $10,350. If you are still confused, I would give a CPA a call and just ask them your question, they should be able to give you an answer for free.

Comment: The Pennsylvania tax brochure [Personal Income Taxes for College Students](http://www.revenue.pa.gov/FormsandPublications/FormsforIndividuals/Documents/Personal%20Income%20Tax/rev-758.pdf) suggests the OP must file with New York *first*, and his resident state of Pennsylvania *second*, claiming a resident tax credit on his PA forms.  While states may make any arrangements, this ordering (non-resident form first, resident form second) matches what I've had to do in every pair of states I've filed.